# IdentityServer4 HTTP urls in discovery document

Tags: linux, azure-web-app-service, identityserver4

I hosted IdentityServer4 in "Azure App Service Linux" environment. 
Endpoint URL's are having HTTP instead of HTTPS

https://jeevesauthenticationservice.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration

I already tried forwardheaders method.

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with Azure app service. Somehow dynamic cache enabled by default. Solved by setting it to 0.